# Posting SO to Acumatica: Branch Cannot Be Empty

Tags: vb.net, soap-client, acumatica

When I try to post a Sales Order to Acumatica using the SOAP API, I get the error

```
'Branch' cannot be empty.
```

I have examined the `SalesOrder` object and do not see any properties named Branch either in `SalesOrder` or in the `SalesOrderDetail`. I have considered that this might be referring to the login information, but the Branch there is set to "Default" and I have been successfully retrieving Item and Customer information with those credentials.

Any insight on what I might need to do to resolve this?

Comment: 'SOOrder' object have a BranchID property however I don't know how that would translate to 'SalesOrder' object in SOAP API.

Comment: Do you know where this is in the interface? I found a Location property, that appears in both the API and the UI, but when I try using that it says `'Location' cannot be found in the system.`

Comment: Okay, I just found it in the UI under Financial Settings, now I'm looking for it in the endpoint mappings.

Comment: It looks like the Financial Information and thus the Branch is exposed in Endpoint version 17.200.001, but not in 6.00.001. It does still fail in 6.00.001 because it's not filled in, though. Should probably update the documentation to deprecate 6.00.001 or something.

Comment: So I connected to 17.200.001, populated Branch with "Default", and am getting the same error. So I went into the UI and tried creating an SO manually, and the Branch is read-only and blank, and gives the same error.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with access rights for that user and branches. I have seen this before but unfortunately I don't remember the fix. Also see if the user has a default branch configured somewhere.

Comment: When you are logging in make sure you are logging in with the Branch Code in the login request not the branch name. I had an issue where it wouldn't let me place a sales order until i was logging in to a valid Branch

Comment: Hi, does the case make difference? MyStore vs MYSTORE?